# C Program for validation of Order

Tags: c

Can anybody help me with my code, I have a problem on my `3. Order`when validating my order if it exceeds the available stocks or Not

```
int main(void){

    int choice = 0;
    int year = 1, i, com;
    int storage[99] = {0};

    for (;;) {

        clrscr();

           printf("Year %d\n\n", year);

           printf("1. Import\n");
           printf("2. Storage\n");
           printf("3. Order\n");

           printf("\nchoice: ");

        scanf("%d", &choice);


        if (choice == 1){ // import

            clrscr();
            printf("Enter sets of computer's imported: ");
            scanf("%d", &storage[year]);
            year++;
        }

        if (choice == 2){ // storage

            clrscr();
            printf("Year    sets\n");

            for (i = 1; i < year; i++){

            printf("%2d     %4d\n", i, storage[i]);

        }

         getch();

        }
        if(choice == 3){ //order

            printf("Enter Sets of Computer ordered: ");
            scanf("%d", &com);

        for (i = 0; com && i < 99; i++){

        if (com <= storage[i]){

            storage[i] = storage[i] - com;
            com = 0;    
        }
        if (com > storage[i]){
        printf("Sorry we have No enough Stocks !");

        }
        if (storage[i] <= com){

            com = com - storage[i];
            storage[i] = 0;
        }
    }


        }
    }
}
```

for example:

I import 3 times in `choice 1. Import`

In `Year 1` i import `500` sets of computers

In `Year 2` i Import `1000` sets of computers

In `Year 3` i Import `800` sets of computers

when viewing my `2. Storage` it will show this

```
Year    sets
 1      500
 2     1000
 3      800
```

total of 2300 sets of computers in my `2. Storage`

now in `3. Order` i enter sets of computer ordered is `5000`.

`5000` is exceeds my stocks in my `2. Storage` so i am expecting that the order will not continue and it will display `Sorry we have No enough Stocks !`

but when viewing `2. Storage` again it shows wrong output

```
Year    sets
 1        0
 2        0
 3        0
```

as you can see its now empty

Comment: It falls upon a person in their life to learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: ... and sorting out the indentation would also help

Comment: I would start by adding up all of the computers in storage, to see how many total computers you have.

Comment: what do you mean adding up all of the computers

Comment: I mean write a `for` loop that adds up all the entries in the `storage` array, to see how many computers are available.

Comment: should i need to change this for (i = 0; com && i < 99; i++) ? or i make another loop